# Seeking a graph algorithm: how to make the graph happy?

Tags: algorithm, graph, bioinformatics

**Background:**

As you can see below, there is an undirected graph on the left of the figure. Vertices are represented by S1,S2 ... S6, and edges are represented by line segments between vertices. Every edge has a weight (the number near the edge), either positive or negative.

**Definitions:**

In the graph, a simple cycle is called a conflicting cycle if it has an odd number of negative edges, and a concordant cycle if an even (or zero) number of negative edges. On the left of the figure below, for example, the graph has two conflicting cycles(S1-S2-S3-S1 and S2-S3-S4-S2), and other cycles are concordant. A graph is called happy if it has no conflicting cycle.

**Objective:**

Make the graph happy by removing some edges, meanwhile ensuring the cost(the sum of absolute values of weights of removed edges) is lowest. In the figure below, for example, after removing the edge (red line segment), there is no conflicting cycles. So the graph becomes happy, and the cost is only 2.

[image: Grahp]

Answer (score 3):

This problem is NP-hard by reduction from maximum cut. Given an instance of maximum cut, multiply all of the edge weights by -1. The constraints of this problem dictate that edges be removed so as to eliminate all odd cycles, i.e., we need to find the maximum-weight bipartite subgraph.

This problem in fact is equivalent to a 2-label unique label cover problem. The goal is to color each vertex black or white so as to minimize the sum of costs for (i) positive edges that connect vertices of different colors (ii) negative edges that connect vertices of the same color. Deleting all of these edges is a valid solution to the original problem. Conversely, given a valid set of edges to delete, we can determine a coloring. I expect that there's an approximation algorithm based on semidefinite programming (and the relaxation could be used for branch and bound).

Unless you're familiar with combinatorial optimization, however, the algorithm that I would suggest is integer programming. Let `x(e)` be 1 if we delete edge `e` and let `x(e)` be 0 if we don't.

```
minimize sum_{edges e} cost(e) x(e)
subject to
for every simple cycle C with an odd number of negative edges,
    sum_{edges e in C} x(e) >= 1
for each edge e, x(e) in {0, 1}
```

The solver will do most of the work. The problem is handling the exponential number of constraints that I've written. The crudest thing to do is to generate all simple cycles and give the solver the whole program. Another possibility is to solve to optimality with a subset of the constraints, test whether the solution is actually valid, and, if not, introduce one or more missing constraints. To do the test, attempt to two-color the undeleted subgraph such that vertices joined by a positive edge have identical colors and vertices joined by a negative edge have different colors. Color greedily; if we get stuck, then there's an odd cycle at fault.

With more sophistication, it's possible to solve the program as written via a technique called [column generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_generation).

Comment: there is also a possibility of removing the positive edges so there is no cycle(no conflicting cycle) at all so contracting the positive edge weight affect that possibility ?

Comment: @VikramBhat Argh, yep. The NP-hardness reduction is intact though.

Comment: I agree with np-hard part as only negative edge elimination is subset of the problem so problem is atleast as hard as it :) +1

Comment: Can you give a few more details on the column generation? What would a column correspond to?

Comment: @FalkHüffner We'd solve the dual program, to get a lower bound for branch and bound. The dual columns would correspond to cycles with an odd number of negative edges. Using the current primal solution as edge weights, we look for an invalid cycle whose sum is less than 1 by computing shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [solver](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/bsg/) for this problem (under the name "Signed Graph Balancing"). It is based on a fixed-parameter algorithm that is fast if only few edges need to be deleted. The method is described in the paper "[Separator-based data reduction for signed graph balancing](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/separator-data-reduction-joco10.pdf)".